# Can I use 2 different passports while traveling? (while living in none of those countries)

Tags: passports

So i have a Syrian passport and and Egyptian one, i work in Russia and my working visa is on my Syrian passport, i wanna travel to Indonesia, going there for Egyptians is visa free.

My question is, Can i leave Russia with my Syrian passport, and enter then leave Indonesia with my Egyptian one, and go back to Russia with my Syrian one (since the visa is on there)?

there are 4 countries involved, 1 visa, and 2 entries! i hope the description makes it clear ^

Comment: Your edit does show you do not really trust the answer to the other question but you can, this is a straight forward 2 passports situation.